# Rakefile not getting deployed with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, capistrano

I am getting this error when deploying with capistrano:

```
executing "cd /opt/my_app/dev/releases/20100103021722; rake RAILS_ENV=staging  db:migrate"
    servers: ["96.30.33.84"]
    [96.30.33.84] executing command
 ** [out :: 96.30.33.84] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: 96.30.33.84] 
 ** [out :: 96.30.33.84] No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
 ** [out :: 96.30.33.84] 
 ** [out :: 96.30.33.84] /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2377:in `raw_load_rakefile'
 ** [out :: 96.30.33.84] 
 ** [out :: 96.30.33.84] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 ** [out :: 96.30.33.84]
```

It randomly just started occurring.  I found out the problem was that my new deploys are missing my rake file...however I am deploying from my staging branch and I can confirm that my staging branch has the Rakefile.  Somehow it's not getting deployed.  Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: it's also not deploying my config/routes.rb file and other files

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using some sort of vcs (svn/git/etc.), have the files been ignored by the repo, ie. they aren't getting deployed with the app, thus not showing up on staging?

Comment: "I can confirm that my staging branch has the Rakefile"

Comment: I thought you meant locally, have you tried running rake remotely? Do you get the same result?

Comment: yes because the Rakefile is missing from the deployed repository.  it is in the git repository i have hosted remotely but it is not in the deployed staging code that i also have hosted remotely.  does that make sense?  not sure how confusing this is to other people...